# Linq2Sql DataContext and TransactionScope, nested the wrong way?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, transactionscope, nested

In our current project it has occurred that we sometimes nest the creation of a DataContext and TransactionScope like this:

```
using(var dc = OurDataContext.CreateInstance())
{
    DoSomething(dc);
    ...
}

void DoSomething(OurDataContext dc)
{
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // DoSomethingElse() might call dc.SubmitChanges() which is why
        // we inserted the TransactionScope here
        DoSomethingElse(dc);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Does this really work as we expect it to?

(Even though deadlines were tight, it's quite embarrassing to discover code like this.)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly the way you'd do it if you had more time, it should work as you expect. You have a transaction scope for a single data context and all your work is being done within the scope of that transaction. It should commit or rollback the way you expect it to.

You probably realize that passing around a data context object probably isn't the most efficient way to share a context object. One possible alternative is to create a context object and then use ThreadStaticObject to share it among methods. We do this quite often.